# Why is isNaN() is undefined?

Tags: undefined, nan

I'm new to this, so wondering if someone could please advise why isNaN() is undefined?

```
package nan;

public class nan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       {
           if (isNaN(1))
           {System.out.println("true");}
       
    };

    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: What host environment are you using? `System.out.println` is not native JavaScript.

Comment: This looks rather like Java.

Answer (score 1):

You want `Double.isNaN` or `Float.isNaN` in Java.